# How to get Implode get data before this string?

Tags: php, explode, implode

My url is
like`http://localhost/manishatutors/tutors-in-city/Crossing-Republik-tutor/`

how could i get `Crossing Republic`
using php

I used

```
<?php

list($a,$page_get) = explode("city/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $array=explode("/",$page_get);
    $getCity1=remove_dash($array[0]);
    $p=$array[1];
        $get_city = implode('-',$getCity1);
print_r($get_city);
?>
```

but its giving 
Crossing republik tutor
while I don't want tutor

Comment: You should update your question instead of posting codes in comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
<?php

list($a,$val) = explode("city/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $array=explode("/",$val);
    $val2=remove_dash($array[0]);
    $p=$array[1];
        $val3= implode('-',$val2);
print_r($val3);
?>
```

**NEW EDITED ANSWER**

```
list($a,$val) = explode("city/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $array=explode("/",$val);
    $val2=$array[0];
    $p=$array[1];
        $val3= implode('-tutor',$val2);
print_r(remove_dash($val3[0]));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use explode function and take the last

```
$req_uris = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $req_uris[count($req_uris)-1];
```

and if you want you can replace dash with space

```
echo str_replace('-', ' ', $req_uris[count($req_uris)-1]);
```

**EDIT**

```
$url = 'http://localhost/manishatutors/tutors-in-city/Crossing-Republik-tutor/';

$exploded = array_values(array_filter(explode('/',$url)));
$last     = $req_uris[count($exploded)-1];

echo str_replace( '-', ' ', str_replace('tutor', '', $last) );
```

change $url with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']